# Congratulations Rickross on being first 100k rep user!

Tags: discussion

HSE has been improving day by day and graduation was one of the milestone we had been waiting for such a long time and it happened last year. For the success of any site, active participations of users matter. And fortunately we have many such active such users. We really appreciate all users for their contributions everyday to improve the site.

Recently, one of our oldest and active user [**Rickross**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross) has reached **100k rep milestone** and he is the **first** to do that on HSE. And we feel this deserves a meta announcement. :)

[image]

**Source link to fetch this data**: [LINK](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/78712/world-cup-of-reputation)

## Congratulations Rickross on completing 100k rep milestone!! We appreciate your active participation on this site. :)

[image: Source of image: img.freepik.com]

<sub>**NOTE:** For users completing 100k rep, some goodies as a token of appreciations will be provided by SE. This may take time though. For any related information, feel free to visit this [**meta post**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back)</sub>

Comment: Why it shows unknown country for me?

Comment: If you're located in gyangunj they won't be able to trace @TheDestroyer

Comment: @Rickross true 

Comment: @Rickross lol..

Comment: Congratulations @Rickross - way to go even more. Your answers on agamas and Tantras are what today is needed to learn for today generation.

Comment: @Rickross Any update on the goodies? :)

Comment: I didn't apply for goodies @SeverusSnape

Comment: Found many of your answers while scrolling through past posts and they were very helpful & informative @Rickross Thx !

Comment: No problem @devibhakt and thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 18):

Thanks for noticing . Equal credit must go to all those too who have read my posts and upvoted them.

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations RickRoss. We saw many hurdles and obstacles to our site and the content contributed by you and your consistency is helping the site continue despite all difficulties.

Comment: Haha ... thanks

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations RR.  When I joined - your answers used to astound me "who'd have thought this is in scripture" and they STILL do.

Comment: Thanks @SK ................

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations Rick Ross, The questions and answers are really great ( I find them very interesting and thought provoking ) Keep asking questions and answers which can help me gain Knowledge :-)

P.S.---->Infact everyone's questions and answers are very much great...I have got to know a lot of things in the past 7 months :-)

Comment: Thanks for your words.

Comment: Welcome Rickross :-)